# HTML files for different screen from asset folder

Tags: android, html, assets

My application contains HTML files and related images.

I sized the images for a screen size (480x800), so that the image can fit for the screen width.

But when My app is on large screen device, the images become smaller.

Do I need to design HTML files for multi-screen?
Or how to make these images fit for all screen size?

Comment: If you fix your image size then for high end devices it may look small.

Comment: If I fixed height and weight on HTML of a large sized image, then what should I do for large screen?

Comment: You should design with large sized screen and let it resize for smaller screen devices if you are using WebView.

Comment: Yep. I am using WebView. But I can't understand how to call or rename html file.

Answer (score 0):

try this css.

```
.myFullScreenImage { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and apply `myFullScreenImage` class to the `<img>` tag like this

```
<img src="source.jpg" class="myFullScreenImage"/>.
```

Let me know if it works.